# Can I do a Partial Cascade Update on a Foreign Key Field Using INSTEAD OF UPDATE Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

[image: Here Is a photo description Of My Example and down the Photo is My Question]

The Challenge is that, when I change the name of One of My Retail Shop I want for the *Sales* Table:

*RetailName* to stay the Deleted name *(I mean the Changed Name)* for records with previous months Sales Date and *RetailName* to be the New Inserted Name for Records from this Month Onward. The reason for doing this is that when I will be searching Sales Table in the future I will be doing so by the Name of the Retail at that time not the new name and also for some other reasons.

I thought of Using an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on table **MyRetails** to Duplicate the Record and change RetailName value on the duplicated record to the New RetailName instead of Updating when a user tries to Update it then using the same trigger to Loop through Sales table so as to change the foreign Key *RetailName* to the newly created One for those records whose Sale Date = This Month, But unfortunately I was Unable to write the T-SQL for that . . .  Also to relate the 2 Names for the One Retail and not to be confused as two Retail Shops I thought of adding a field which will contain values that will categorize the 2 Records together.

Can Somebody help to tackle this problem?

**NB:** Don't wonder why I Used RetailName As PK instead of RetailID, it was meant to be like that for some reasons.

Comment: "Don't wonder why I Used RetailName As PK instead of RetailID, it was meant to be like that for some reasons." - erm.....

Comment: "Has to be" isn't a good reason. Considering that using names as a Primary Key is often a very poor choice for a key candidate, then "has to" isn't a good reason. A Primary Key should be a static value, never changing. The fact that you need the value to change means that it is **not** a good PK candidate; you might have a "has to be the primary key" requirement, but design requirements effectively say it "must not be the primary key candidate".

Comment: Arguably this is all unnecessary anyway. There is no real relationship between each of these tables and `MyRetails`, each one should just have their own `RetailName` and `Description`, there is no need for the extra table and foreign key.

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/912274/can-i-do-a-partial-cascade-update-on-a-foreign-key.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an answer for you, but let me first clarify:

The reasons you have chosen RetailName instead of some ID are **wrong**, and **you probably will pay dearly in the future for that choice**.

But people need to learn the hard way sometimes, so here goes:

Your thoughts (apart from the earlier points) are sound. No need for an instead-of trigger, though; an AFTER trigger will work fine.
Adding a field to connect them seems sound, let's call them [MyRetailsGroup] and populate it:

```
alter table [MyRetails] add [MyRetailsGroup] nvarchar(100) -- or whatever datatype [RetailName] is
update MyRetails set [MyRetailsGroup]=[MyRetails]
```

The trigger sould look something like this:

```
create or alter trigger TR_MyRetails_update_PK on [MyRetails]
after update as
begin
    if update([RetailName]) -- only run for primary key change
    begin
    
        -- create new rows for previous PK
        insert [MyRetails]([RetailName],[Description],[MyRetailsGroup])
            select 
                d.[RetailName],d.[Description],d.[MyRetailsGroup]
            from deleted d
                
        -- save previous and next PK to temp table
        select d.[RetailName] as [original],i.[RetailName] as [new]
        into #mr
        from
            inserted i
            inner join deleted d on i.[RetailName]=d.[RetailName]
            
        -- now do your business stuff with those pairs
        update sales set [RetailName]=mr.[new]
        from
            [Sales] sales
            inner join #mr mr on mr.[original]=sales.[RetailName]
        where sales.[Date] >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) -- this month onward
        
        ......
    end
end
```

Comment: OK Lets Say I choosed RetailID As my PK, in My Frontend's Form for Example MS Access, what will be the the RetailsName shop in January's Sales when I changed the name in March?

Comment: Two ideas: 1) You only keep RetailID as PK, and since you care about name historically, you make a new table with RetailID,name,date period, and you can get the name from there with the appropriate join. or 2) You have both RetailID as PK but also RetailName on [Sales], on which you store the RetailName of the time you want. This means that you have a trigger that looks a bit like the one above, but at least you don't have the weird [MyRetailsGroup] column since the ID correctly connects them, and you still keep the FK.

Comment: Table MyRetails conflicted with all the relationship, then I decided to delete all my relations to table MyRetails, After doing so It duplicates the PK very Nicely but doesn't work on table Sales, Whats wrong?